# how to add fading and transitions when adding the innerText of a div in javascript

Tags: html, button, transition, innertext

just like in the "phone" app of an android phone I want that each input should have a transition and some fading effects. This is because am trying to duplicate that kind of app using JS

try looking at this photo to see the project and what I need
[image]

Comment: Can you provide any html/css/js so we can have a starting point to help direct you?

Comment: Please read: [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.